# using BETWEEN operator twice in one SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This is what I have tried, but did not work.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS month_count
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE
     `meta_key`='from_dt' AND
      (`meta_value` BETWEEN '$st' AND '$end') AND
      (`meta_value` BETWEEN '$st1' AND '$end1');
```

I'm trying to count the number of months which come between epoch time of $st and $end of this year & between $st1 and $end1 of next year. Say I have 2 dates (feb 2013 and feb 2014)in meta_value fields, I want the query to return 2(as there are 2 February's).

How to use 2 between operators in one sql statement?

Comment: The `meta_value` cannot be two different values at the same time, do you mean `OR`?

Comment: Actually i'm trying to count the number of months which come between epoch time of $st and $end of this year & $st1 and $end1 of next year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing technically wrong with your query, but depending on your desired results, you probably want to be using `OR` -- just make sure your parentheses are in the correct place:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS month_count
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE
     `meta_key`='from_dt' AND
      ((`meta_value` BETWEEN '$st' AND '$end') OR
      (`meta_value` BETWEEN '$st1' AND '$end1'))
```

Your current query is requiring the meta_value be between both sets of numbers which may be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS month_count
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE
      (`meta_key`='from_dt' AND `meta_value` BETWEEN '$st' AND '$end') OR
      (`meta_key`='from_dt' AND `meta_value` BETWEEN '$st1' AND '$end1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for two different rows that are in these ranges.  For that, use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS month_count
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE `meta_key`='from_dt'
having sum(case when `meta_value` BETWEEN '$st' AND '$end' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 AND
       sum(case when `meta_value` BETWEEN '$st1' AND '$end1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS month_count 
FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE `meta_key`='from_dt' AND
(`meta_value` BETWEEN '$st' AND '$end') OR (`meta_value` BETWEEN '$st1' AND '$end1');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want an     OR    there instead of an     AND. Think that in an     AND  bith conditions must be satisfied whereas in an OR one condition is enough.